# Why am I question limited? I only have two questions

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, post-ban

Why have I reached a question limit?   I have only asked two questions.

Comment: @JackO You'll need to provide the exact message you got.

Comment: Also while waiting on the moderator, please understand that deleted questions count to the ban, including questions deleted both by you and by site members. Good luck, and I hope that you figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

In your case; you're right: You only have two questions total.

You ended up getting a temporary block due to the votes and the questions themselves. It looks like you [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831267/how-to-use-selected-in-select-form-when-populating-select-form-from-database); it was closed as a duplicate, and [so you re-posted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858261/marking-select-form-dropdown-as-selected-when-error).

With the exception of the "This question is different:" and "or not valid", the questions were identical.

I'm not even a beginner in PHP, so the [original listed duplicate source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work) may solve your problem. If it does not, please [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831267/how-to-use-selected-in-select-form-when-populating-select-form-from-database) to let us know why it didn't solve your issue.

It is also helpful to edit your first question if you need additional criteria for the same task instead of posting a whole new question.  One task = One question.

Comment: I did exactly that, and no one ever replied or unlocked the first question.  That is why I posted it again.  It does not match the question.

Comment: @jackO the guidance could certainly be improved but the hope is that you’ll read the linked duplicate; try it out; and edit your question to let us know in part why the duplicate we linked you to did not solve your problem.  This means you should edit that same question that was closed. When you edit it, it’ll be put into a review queue and people will take a look. If it’s sufficiently edited to no longer be a duplicate it’ll be voted to reopened.

Comment: I deleted them.

Comment: @jackO deleted questions still count towards the ban.

Comment: How do I just delete this account?  I will go elsewhere...

Comment: This ban feels like a very harsh reaction to a user's first two questions (admittedly I can't see them, but surely one re-posting by an inexperienced user should not cause a ban, rather a warning).

Comment: Strictly-speaking it's more of a rate-limit than a ban, @Mandy - the rate varies based on the reception of recent posts.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you enlighten me and George what the exact message was that user got? I initially dupe hammered against the same dupe George now has selected but when he re-opened and asked for the exact message I realized the rate limit might be in play. But I always fail to find the correct post that explains this specific rate-limit. Having the error message might help with that.

Comment: @rene https://i.stack.imgur.com/eudz1.png